# Ansible: Reload container if previous tasks resulted in changed==true?

Tags: ansible, ansible-2.x, docker-container

How do I configure a docker_container task to restart a container if specific prior tasks resulted in changed==true?

Say I have three copy tasks(A,B,C) and then a docker_container task with state=started.

How do I have a docker_container task perform a restart if copy task A or copy task C resulted in changed==true?

If task A and task C both result in changed==false and the docker_container would otherwise not restart the container, then ansible should NOT restart the container.

Comment: I would say that what matches the more what you are describing here is using [handlers](https://docs.ansible.com/ansible/latest/user_guide/playbooks_handlers.html#handler-example)

Answer (score 3):

There's an easier way which doesn't require you to duplicate the container parameters in the handler - use the `restart` parameter:

```yaml
- name: Create config file
  ansible.builtin.template:
    src: config.yml.j2
    dest: /etc/config.yml
  register: foobar_config

- community.general.docker_container:
    name: foobar
    image: "{{ foobar_image }}"
    restart_policy: always
    restart: "{{ foobar_config.changed | default(false) }}"
    volumes:
      - "/etc/config.yml:/etc/conf.yml"
```

Comment: How would I do this with more than one template task? Such that if any template changed the doctor container should restart?

Comment: Is that `| default(false)` necessary though? it provides protection when the variable doesn't exist but it won't happen in this case.

Answer (score 1):

You can simply use a handler for this.

```yaml
---
 - name: Testplaybook
   hosts: ...

   handlers:
     - name: restart docker
       ...

   tasks:
    - name: Copy A
      copy:
        ...
      notify: restart docker
    - name: Copy B
      copy:
        ...
    - name: Copy C
      copy:
        ...
      notify: restart docker
```

This will restart your docker container if copy A and/or copy C changes.
The handlers will be run at the end of the playbook (or when a task see below asks for it) and multiple notify events of the same category will only restart the container once.

If you want your restart right after the copy tasks you can add a task:

```yaml
- name: Flush handlers
  meta: flush_handlers
```

Comment: As a task, docker_container, will do a restart if it sees an container image update.
How do I have the docker_container handler also run under its own task change logic?